# How to fix another drop-down value after selecting first in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one one form with 2 drop-downs.
What i want is, when I select 1st drop down box, then a specific option gets fixed (which can't be change by user in that form) to another drop-down box. How can i do this in javascript or jquery?

```
<select id="item_type" name="item_type" style="width:300px;" ">
                              <option value=''>-- Select --</option>
                              <option value="City">City</option>
                              <option value="Source">Source</option>
                              <option value="Follow Up">Follow Up</option>
                              <option value="Next Day">Next Day</option>                            
</select> 

<select id="item_value_type" name="item_value_type" style="width:300px;" ">
                              <option value=''>-- Select --</option>
                              <option value="value">value</option>
                              <option value="id">id</option>                            
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The jQuery way would be**

```
var valueType = $('#item_value_type')
$('#item_type').on('change', function(e) {
  valueType.val('thefixedvalue'); // sets the value
  valueType.attr('disabled', true); //disables the select
});
```

To reenable the select, just use

```
valueType.removeAttr('disabled');
```

**The javascript way is**

```
var valueType = document.getElementById('item_value_type');
var itemType = document.getElementById('item_type');
itemType.onchange = function(event) {
  valueType.value = 'yourFixedValue';
  valueType.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

reenable the select with:

```
valueType.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<select id="item_type" name="item_type" style="width:300px" onchange=javascript:change(this.value)>
         <option value=''>-- Select --</option>
         <option value="City">City</option>                         
</select>
```

and in change function you can modify other select field.drop-down box.

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery:**

```
$("#target_sel").attr("disabled",true);
$("#first_sel").on("change",function(){
   $("#target_sel").val($(this).val())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/LXRqm/

API: `change`: http://api.jquery.com/change/ `prop`: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

you can also do `prop('disabled', false)` to set it in active state.

Hope this helps, and feel free to play around with demo,

**code**

```
var secondSelect = $('#item_value_type');
var hulkChange = "value";

$('#item_type').change(function() {
     secondSelect.val(hulkChange); 
     secondSelect.prop('disabled', true);
});​
```